# Regex - searching between strings with new lines

Tags: regex

Preconditions:

```
[numbers]
[vip]111,222[vip]
[standard]333[standard]
[numbers]
```

What I want:
Find everything between [numbers]
Problem:
When this text is in one line the solution is simple

```
(?<=\[numbers\])(.*?)(?=\[numbers\])
```

But it is possible to search when new line are like in preconditions?

Comment: From the `[regex]` tag description: `"Please include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using, together with this tag."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in most regex varieties the dot (.) stands for anything ON THE LINE.

You can scan across end-of-lines by using an expression for "anything", for example:

(?<=\[numbers\]) ( [\d\D]*? ) (?=\[numbers\])

as [\d\D] stands for 'anything that is a digit, or anything that is NOT a digit'

Comment: Of course... now I see that I had lack of nowlage about dot... Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a regex for the presented problem, with `awk` it's enough to set the record separator:

```
 awk 1 RS='\\[numbers\\]\n' ORS=''
```

Output:

```
[vip]111,222[vip]
[standard]333[standard]
```